# Play a beep sound on onboard speaker using PHP

Tags: php, speaker

I want to play an beep sound on internal(on-board) speaker to alert the user about a specific activity on a webpage.

Is it possible in PHP?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Please post the code you have and what errors you are getting.  You may also need look at [ask].

Comment: No, I googled it but didnt found anything helpful to try it out

Comment: PHP is a server side script not a client side function to trigger functions in client machine. Go for Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, not on the client's machine anyway. PHP is a back-end language that uses HTML / CSS as a front-end output, thus you can't do anything to the user's machine that the front-end languages can't do (HTML, CSS, Javascript)